# Is it possible to add text to a specific position in JavaFX (JavaFX 2) chart?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

I am creating a LineChart with JavaFX. What I need is to put 3 text labels at 3 coordinate positions (0,15) (0,60) (0,78).

Is it possible to do that? I don't see a way to add text in a JavaFx chart except axis labels.

Comment: I think, It is reachable with XYChart.Data.nodeProperty() and Region implementation playing. You should set a node property to be some custom implementation of Region, which will create some symbol, and a text node. But you shouldn't get text node into account, when implement width and height answers of your region.

Comment: BTW, remove "javaFX" tag. We talk about JavaFX-2

Comment: But at the same time, seems, you cannot add labels at a custom place, you want. I think, you will have to implement subclass of chart, and add your own functionality in chart items allocation